# CSS Page peel bottom together with shadow left and right

Tags: css, shadow, css-shapes

I would like to create this page (see image) with css shadow. Is this possible? So to have the page peel css box shadow bottom left and right and the shadow left and right?[image]

Comment: Why not just look at the page elements with Dev Tools to get more an idea of how they did it from wherever you took this from?

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Comment: the above was done by myself but with bg images in a div construct. now i want to change it to css, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`. Creating two new areas which have their own box-shadows and placing them where required you can create the illusion of the shadow getting bigger as the page goes down.

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
div {
  background: white;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  height: 97%;
  z-index: -10;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 30%;
  top: 2%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  right: 8px;
  left: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
```

An alternative is using CSS transforms to change the perspective of a single `:before` pseudo element.

This was done by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) [**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24101673#24101673)

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
div {
  background: white;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px -10px gray, -10px 0px 5px -10px gray;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(1deg);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px gray, -5px 0px 10px gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

- [CSS `:before` & `:after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)